# Work with multiple selections simultaneously in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I am using Photoshop CS5 to work with an image that will be composed of about forty separate pieces that I want to be able to move and rotate independently, something like a jigsaw puzzle.

I don't believe I can have more than one selection per layer, so I am expecting to have one layer per piece.

Is there a way that the move tool can operate on whichever selection is under the mouse pointer instead of having to switch between layers or control-clicking the selection? I really want it to behave as if all the selections are on a single layer, but with their own z-order

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the end-goal. You say rotate/move independently but then want to move whatever is under the mouse. Which is it? Would making a Folder on your layers and putting them all in there do what you're after?

Comment: I believe the poster is asking if the courser can work like Illustrator. I cant answer, i don't know.

Comment: @Ryan: Do you mean a layer group? I tried that, but it loses the ability to move each selection independently. As I said, I want it as though I just had a number of selections that I could work on independently but all on the same layer. At present it's like working on a forty-piece jigsaw with a sheet of glass between each piece

Comment: @Daniel: You may be right but I don't know as I have no experience with Illustrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Daniel is correct in your functionality once he mentioned that. The closest I believe you'll get is using Folders to contain all of your "pieces." If you're not aware you can then Right Click and any object directly under the mouse appears in a drop down. You could quickly select the Group / Folder Name or quickly select one of the singular items within it. Notice Rectangle 1 (the red one) isn't on the drop down, because my cursor is not on top of it. Sorry not using Screencap software but I right-clicked directly left of where the Group 1 appeared:

[image]

I can't think of any more efficient way within Photoshop to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Okay that's great, thank you. I was coming round to thinking that what I want isn't possible. I've never heard them called *folders* before so I wasn't sure what you meant. It does help to know that you can right-click anywhere and see a list of everything under the cursor - the fastest way I knew to switch layers is to control-click somewhere.

Comment: @Borodin Glad that will work for you. The icon is a Folder so I'm just in the probably bad habit of calling them that.

Comment: Or maybe I'll treat myself to a copy of Illustrator! Thanks for your time